# Charts become blank when knitting to HTML if i include a specific chart

Tags: r

I've been drafting an html report and it's been going grand with the report nearly completed, but i've come across a new issue I can't resolve. Now whenever I knit the document, all the text and tables are rendered fine, but the report only renders the first chart and then all others come up as blank spaces. The knitting process works through the steps fine with no error messages, but the output just leaves blank gaps where the charts should be.

The first chart is created with plotly, but the rendered chart is just a static image and when i exclude the code for this chart by commenting it out, the document knits perfectly with all the charts included (obviously minus this problem chart). I have tried moving the code chunk for the chart below other charts, and when knitted, the charts above it in the code render perfectly, but the ones below it are just blank.

Here's the code chunk for the chart that's causing the other charts to become blank.

```
#making vertical line for UK average
vline <- function(x = 0, color = "red") {
  list(type = "line", y0 = 0, y1 = 1, yref = "paper", x0 = x, x1 = x,
    line = list(color = "red", dash="dot", linewidth = 15))}

#setting style for hover labels
hoverfonts <- list(
  color = "white")
hoverlabels <- list(
  bordercolor = "transparent",
  font = hoverfonts)

#styling and placing label for UK average vertical line
UK <- list(x = 22, y = 'South East', text = "UK Average: 22%",
  xref = "x", yref = "y", showarrow = TRUE, arrowhead = 8, ax = 70, ay = -40, font = list(color = "red", family = 'sans serif',size = 16))

Figure_1 <- plot_ly(Figure1,
                x = ~DisabilityRate,
                y = ~Country,
                type = 'bar',
                #colors= ~ColourGroup,
                orientation = 'h',
                #changes orientation of bars to horizontal to fit LGD names
                #Removed labels for now as they were duplicating
                hoverlabel = hoverlabels,
                #hoverlabel = list(font=list(color="white")),
                # text = ~DisabilityRate, textposition = 'auto',
                #change colours depending on geography grouping
                marker = list(color = ifelse(Figure1$ColourGroup == 1, "#B07BD7",
                                      ifelse(Figure1$ColourGroup == 2, "#203864",
                                      ifelse(Figure1$ColourGroup == 4, "#8FAADC",
                                      "#4472C4"))))
           #      add_text(showlegend = FALSE, x = c(24), y = c("Inner London"),
           # text = c("UK: 22%"))
                )
  # remove modebar as it overlaps with title
config(Figure_1, displayModeBar = FALSE)%>% layout(
  #title element not used here as it's long and doesn't size well when magnified. If using test at 400% zoom
  xaxis = list(title = ""),
  yaxis = list(title = "")
) %>%
  #Making the xaxis start at zero and placing vertical line on chart
  layout(xaxis = list(rangemode='tozero',ticksuffix = "%"), shapes = list(vline(22)))%>%
  layout(annotations = UK)%>%
  layout(margin=list(pad=5))

# Create the CSV and Excel Files
downloadButtons(data = Figure1[,c('Country','DisabilityRate')],
           title = "Figure 1: Disability Prevalence by Region/Country")
```

Is there anything in my code that would be causing this? Any help would be appreciated.